# salt git.latest not connecting to github repo

Tags: git, salt-stack

We have a state as below:

```
Some_ID:
  git.latest:
    - name: https://github.com/SomeRepo/SomeDir.git
    - target: /path/to/some/dir
```

When calling the state it fails with below error:

Failed to check remote refs: error: Failed connect to github.com:443; Operation now in progress while accessing https://github.com/SomeRepo/SomeDir.git/info/refs

The minion is behind a proxy and we have tried specifying the proxy server in the .gitconfig file and we are seeing the minion requests for this repo in the proxy server logs. The minion is able to clone the repo successfully when we run git clone on the minion.

salt 2016.3.2 (Boron)

Anyone have any insights?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here was with salt not being able to see the home environment.. Setting the home env with salt before the git clone gets executed resolved this issue.

Comment: Could you be a little bit more clear? Do you mean the `cwd` key?